# I am trying to make a website using streamlit on streamlit cloud, but it is having problems downloading a python library

Tags: python, github, streamlit, geopy

It is not downloading Geopy for some reason. I want to try to manually do this but I am not sure how.

I have restarted the whole process but it gave the same error. It says that it cannot find a module called 'geopy'. If there is any way to manually install Geopy, please let me know.

Comment: Works fine in my case and I am not able to reproduce it. Might be an issue of python not being configured properly. Are you using a virtual environment or the base python?

Comment: I am using anaconda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manually download Geopy, go to your site. Then go to Manage App. Then, click on the three dots and go to Your Apps. Find the site that you're working on, and then click on those three dots. Click "edit with codespace.". There, you can manually install the libraries through the terminal.

Comment: tysm this works